# error: (-215:Assertion failed) length > FLT_EPSILON in function 'unclip' in Text Detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, opencv, east-text-detector

I am using text detection in OpenCV, specifically `cv2.dnn_TextDetectionModel_DB`

Here's the code:

```
text_detector = cv2.dnn_TextDetectionModel_DB("resources/DB_IC15_resnet50.onnx")
binThresh = 0.3;
polyThresh = 0.5;
maxCandidates = 200;
unclipRatio = 2.0;
text_detector.setBinaryThreshold(binThresh).setPolygonThreshold(polyThresh).setMaxCandidates(maxCandidates).setUnclipRatio(unclipRatio)
text_detector.setInputParams(1.0, (320, 320), (123.68, 116.78, 103.94) , True)


boxes, confs = text_detector.detect(image)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I get the error for the `detect()` function.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. This error is occurring because I have not used the correct parameters.

```
text_detector = cv2.dnn_TextDetectionModel_DB("resources/DB_TD500_resnet50.onnx")
binThresh = 0.3
polyThresh = 0.5
maxCandidates = 200
unclipRatio = 2.0

text_detector.setBinaryThreshold(binThresh).setPolygonThreshold(polyThresh).setMaxCandidates(maxCandidates).setUnclipRatio(unclipRatio)
text_detector.setInputParams(1.0/255, (736, 736), (122.67891434, 116.66876762, 104.00698793) , True)
```